# Why is the ACS712 VIOUT more stable with a current limiting resistor?

Tags: capacitor, current-measurement

Below is my circuit for an ACS712 that is connected to a relay that joins to s capacitor bank:
[image]

In the diagram I using two 5V power supply, one for relay module and one for (PIC, voltage reference, ACS712, opamps and 16x2 LCD screen) which is more sensitive toward voltage noise and I do not want input to be affected.
Attached the picture of the adapter.
[image]

I have an issue with unstable VIOUT reading when connecting a pure capacitor load.

The VIOUT can shift from 2.56 V to 2.524 V (with a fixed supply of 5.13 V) at the trigger of the capacitor bank. After I connected a resistor (51 ohm) in series with the capacitor bank that consists of 1, 1.25 and 0.67 uF capacitors, the VIOUT is very stable - it only shifted 0.02 V to 0.04 V from original value. Does in rush current really play an important role in influence the stability of VIOUT reading? I tried with an inductor of 22 uH before. This method did not work. I also connected a decoupling capacitor to remove noise, this method did not work well to stabilize of VIOUT. Below is the picture of my capacitor connection with resistor.

[image]

Comment: Is the ASC712 ground pin connected to your circuit common? It appears to be only connected to the low-pass filter capacitor (schematic is really hard to read - hint, turn the grid off) unless the GND label connects it to the ground symbol.

Comment: I using two 5V adapter to provide separate supply for relay module and ACS712 current sensor. Both supply ground is connected together otherwise my relay module cannot trigger on by the PIC. Only the acs712 sensor i connected a low pass filter cap.

Comment: Can you update your schematic with said power supplies and how they are connected?